# Error - Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s)

Tags: powershell, exception, export-to-csv

Scenario: There is a PowerShell script being executed using SQL server agent job. It should read a ".xlt" file from location 1, copy it to location 2 and convert it into a CSV or excel file at location 2.

Below is the script :

```
New-PSDrive -Name "UNCPath" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\vpmcc-file1\share3"

$OrgnFile = "UNCPath:\Teams_Shared\120820.xlt"
$CSVFile = "C:\DataFiles\BDM_Test.csv"
$OrgnFileExists = Test-Path $OrgnFile
If ($OrgnFileExists -eq $True)
{      
    Copy-item "UNCPath:\Teams_Shared\120820.xlt" –destination "C:\DataFiles\120820.xlt" -Force
     
    $strFileName = "C:\DataFiles\120820.xlt"
    $strSheetName = 'systemTemplateDeath_15971913000$'
    $strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    $strDataSource = "Data Source = $strFileName"
    $strExtend = "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';" 
    $strQuery = "Select [DDetails.Name.FamilyName],[DDetails.Name.FirstGivenName],[DDetails.Name.OtherGivenNames],[DDetails.Sex],[DDetails.Age],[DDetails.AgeUnit],[DDetails.DateOfBirth.ToDate.Date],
        [DDetails.Place.SuburbTownCity],[DDetails.Place.StateTerritory],[DDetails.Place.ProvinceCountyRegion],[DDetails.Place.Country],[DDetails.DateOfDeath.ToDate.Date],[DDetails.WhereDidDeathOccur],
        [DDetails.HospitalName],[DDetails.HospitalTownSuburbCity],[DDetails.NursingHomeName],[DDetails.NursingHomeTownSuburbCity],[DDetails.Location],[DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.Line1],
        [DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.Line2],[DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.Suburb],[DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.State],[DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.Postcode],[DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.International],
        [DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.ProvinceCountyRegion],[DDetails.PlaceOfDeathAddress.Country] from [$strSheetName]"

    $objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$strProvider;$strDataSource;$strExtend")
    $sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery)
    $sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
    
    $objConn.open()
    $da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($sqlCommand)
    $dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
    [void]$da.fill($dt)
    $objConn.close()

   $dt | Export-Csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
}
Else
{
Exit
}
```

The copy part of the script is working fine but it is not converting the ".xlt" file to CSV format. The script throws error, error message is :

```
Executed as user: PMVS\SVC_SqlServerAgentAccnt. A job step received an error at line 29 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is '    [void]$da.fill($dt)  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "'' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.
```

Can someone please help with this error. This script is a copy of already working script that reads and copies the excel file finally converting it into CSV format.
Only file names, worksheet name and column names have been changed in that working script.

Comment: I think it's the ```$``` at the end of your sheet name ```systemTemplateDeath_15971913000$``` which is giving the ```'' is not a valid name.``` error - if I try it here I get different errors for ```Select [xyz] from [badname]``` (error ```could not find the object 'badname'```) and ```Select [xyz] from [badname$]``` (error ```'badname$' is not a valid name.```). As a test, rename the sheet in the Excel file to remove the trailing ```$```and see if that works.

Comment: Removed the $ sign from worksheet ,now it gives below error :- PowerShell script error. The corresponding line is '    [void]$da.fill($dt)  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'systemTemplateDeath_15971913000'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'systemTemplateDeath_15971913000' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."  '.